# Initially Hide the JQTouch Floaty Bar

Tags: jqtouch

I would like to hide the floaty bar for jqtouch when the page initially loads. Then use the toggle as normal.

Floaty Bar: http://jqtouch.com/preview/demos/ext_floaty/#test

---

$(function(){

```
            $('#togglefloaty').click(function(){
                $('.floaty').toggleFloaty();
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                return false;
            });

            $('#hidefloaty').click(function(){
                $('.floaty');
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                return false;
            });

            $('.floaty').makeFloaty({
                spacing: 20,
                time: '.3s'
            });
```

---

---

How It Works

---

The Floaty bar!
            Testing multiple lines
            Should be flexible.

---

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it, but this might work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.floaty').removeClass('active');
});
```

Then it will be hidden until you add the active class.